# TSQL loop over base tables and add schema details in the output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the sql below: What I am trying to do is have the databasename, schema and also table at the beginning. Also for the TQL to loop through every tables in a database that only looks at base_tables.

Please can someone help.

Thank you

```
            DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(255) = N'AdventureWorksDW2012'
            DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(255) = N'dbo'
            DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255) = N'DimProduct'


            BEGIN


            SET NOCOUNT ON


            -- Declare the parameters internal to query
            DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
            DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''


            DECLARE @ColumnList TABLE (
            ColumnId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
            , [Database] NVARCHAR(255)
            , ColumnName NVARCHAR(255)
            , ColumnMaxLength INT
            , ColumnAVGLength int
            , ColumnMinLength INT
            )


            DECLARE @ColumnMaxLength INT
            declare @ColumnAVGLength int
            DECLARE @ColumnMinLength INT
            DECLARE @ColumnCount INT = 0


            DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1
            DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(255)



            SET @SQLString = 
            N'SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, COLUMN_NAME FROM ' 
            + @DatabaseName + N'.' + N'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE 
            DATA_TYPE IN (''CHAR'', ''NCHAR'', ''VARCHAR'', ''NVARCHAR'')
            and table_catalog = @DatabaseName
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
            AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName'


            SET @ParamDefinition = N' @Databasename NVARCHAR(255),   @SchemaName NVARCHAR(255), @TableName NVARCHAR(255)'


            INSERT INTO @ColumnList (ColumnName)
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParamDefinition, @Databasename, @SchemaName, @TableName


            SELECT @ColumnCount = COUNT(*) FROM @ColumnList


            WHILE (@LoopCounter <= @ColumnCount)
            BEGIN


            SELECT @ColumnName = ColumnName 
            FROM @ColumnList 
            WHERE ColumnId = @LoopCounter


            SET @SQLString = 
            N'SELECT '
            + '@ColumnMinLength = MIN(LEN(' + @ColumnName + '))'
            + ', @ColumnAVGLength = AVG(LEN(' + @ColumnName + '))'
            + ', @ColumnMaxLength = MAX(LEN(' + @ColumnName + '))'
            + ' FROM '
            + @DatabaseName + N'.' + @SchemaName + N'.' + @TableName
            + ' WITH (NOLOCK) '


            SET @ParamDefinition = N'@ColumnMinLength INT OUTPUT, @ColumnAVGLength  INT OUTPUT   ,@ColumnMaxLength INT OUTPUT'


            EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParamDefinition, @ColumnMinLength OUTPUT, @ColumnAVGLength output, @ColumnMaxLength OUTPUT


            UPDATE @ColumnList
            SET 
            ColumnMinLength = @ColumnMinLength
            ,ColumnAVGLength =  @ColumnAVGLength
            , ColumnMaxLength = @ColumnMaxLength
            WHERE ColumnId = @LoopCounter


            SET @LoopCounter += 1


            END


            SELECT 
            ColumnName AS [Column Name]
            , ColumnMinLength AS [Column Minimum Length]
            , ColumnAVGLength as [Column average Length]
            , ColumnMaxLength AS [Column Maximum Length]
            FROM @ColumnList
            ORDER BY [Column Name]


            END
```

Comment: From your question, I'm not sure what currently is lacking. Could you please clarify what's not currently working?

Comment: also what do you mean by `Base Tables` ?

Comment: I would like to loop through the above SQL which isn't quite right in terms of giving me what I need in the output which needs, databasename, schemaname. addition to that I would like it too loop over every tables in the database. By base tables I mean just tables and not views or other objects

Comment: @M.Ali It is what the built in INFORMATION_SCHEMA calls tables e.g. SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES one of the columns will show if it is a view or a "base table"